# I can't install Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot]

when I install VScode in Win10 I've got this alert. What's wrong with it?

Comment: This only happens on my Windows machine (Windows 10 - surface book); I also use a Mac and VSCode extensions and VSCode updates install perfectly fine.

The problem occurs both on the Microsoft Corp network and my home network so I'm not sure it's a proxy issue - I was able to install extensions a month or two ago with all of the same configuration. It really just seems like VSCode can't make any kind of outbound connections if that makes any sense.

I've also uninstalled, restarted, reinstalled to see if that helps with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

- [How to fix - Error 5: Access is Denied in Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-fix-error-5-access-is-denied-in-windows-10/8a4069ea-4b0e-4517-9d7a-62c44b4d6e7d?auth=1)
- [RegCreateKeyEx failed; Code 5. "Access is denied"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/regcreatekeyex-failed-code-5-access-is-denied/4582dba7-b250-4974-85e3-a9838a212aa1?auth=1)
- [Error creating registry key: Code 5](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/error-creating-registry-key-code-5/ba4d24b0-413e-4c38-9dcb-3a0463cf8684?auth=1)

First try to run the installer again with Administrator mode.
And then do follow the below mentioned steps and check if it helps.

Method 1:

Right-clicking on it and select Properties from context menu.

Go to the Security tab and click Advanced. Check the box at the bottom of this window. It is labeled "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object" and then click Ok.

Method 2:

- Press Windows Key + R, type netplwiz
- Click and highlight the User profile, which you want to make administrator
- Click on Properties, then select the Group Membership tab
- Select the Administrator, Click apply/ok

Comment: I've tried,but it didn't work. I also reboot my pc

Comment: Close the antivirus program and try again?

Comment: But I have no antivirus program except Windows Defender

Comment: I just edit my answer and check if it helps.

Comment: I repaired it by deleting the same name of registry, but thanks for your answer, helps me a lot.